# How do I compare two CFUUIDs (Mac OS X Carbon/CoreFoundation)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-carbon, uuid, core-foundation

How can I compare two `CFUUIDRef`s from the CoreFoundation Carbon framework in Mac OS X? Is there an easier way to check if two CFUUIDs are equal other than converting them to strings and then comparing those?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [CFUUID](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/) is a kind of [CFType](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/), so you would use the same [CFEqual](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/CFEqual) function you use for any other CF objects.

Comment: Specifically, if you look at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.19/CFUUID.c, you'll see that it specifies NULL for its equals function pointer, which means (see http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFRuntime.c) that CFEqual will compare UUIDs using the default implementation of pointer identity comparison + type id comparison, which is correct because they're uniqueing. (note that __CFUUIDCreateWithBytesPrimitive calls __CFUUIDAddUniqueUUID)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a canonical or recommended method per se, but would the following suffice?

```
#define CompareUUIDs(u1, u2) memcmp(CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(u1), CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(u2))
```

It would be used as follows:

```
if (CompareUUIDs(u1, u2) == 0) {
    // UUIDs are equal
} // etc..
```

---

Alternatively, as you're only really interested in whether they are equal or not:

```
#define UUIDsAreEqual(u1, u2) (memcmp(CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(u1), CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(u2)) == 0)
```

It would be used as follows:

```
if (UUIDsAreEqual(u1, u2)) {
    // UUIDs are equal
} // etc..
```

Comment: D'oh, I'm an idiot. I've just replicated `CFEqual`, albeit exceptionally poorly. Refer to Peter Hosey's response instead. :-)